# selective 3d plot coloring on gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I've found examples of gnuplot 3d coloring here: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/pm3d.html

Now I'm wonderring whether I can plot two datasets in the same plot while the first one is colored with pm3d and the second one is plotted only as mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Would have been enough to look through the examples of the page you linked, especially the third last one.

A simple example is:

```
set samples 40, 40
set isosamples 40, 40
set ticslevel 0
splot -x**2 with lines, x**2 with pm3d
```

This gives (with 4.6.3):

[image]

Comment: Oh my god. I missed it. Thank you so much.